# How is objects created by configuring the config files (like WCF)

Tags: wcf

I want to create a framework , which should be configurable through App.config.
just like our WCF Host

To make it clear

I need to only write the 3 line to host the service with the below configuration

```
Type serviceType = typeof(DerivativesCalculatorServiceType);
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(serviceType))
host.Open();
```

WCF configuration

```
<configuration>
   <system.serviceModel>
      <services>
         <service name="DerivativesCalculator.DerivativesCalculatorServiceType" 
                  behaviorConfiguration="DerivativesCalculatorService">

            <endpoint  address="Calculator"  
                       binding="basicHttpBinding" 
                       contract="DerivativesCalculator.IDerivativesCalculator"/>
         </service>
      </services>
      <behaviors>
         <serviceBehaviors>
             <behavior name="DerivativesCalculatorService">
                 <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
             </behavior>
         </serviceBehaviors>
      </behaviors>
   </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I want to know how is the binding object, endpoint object, Contract created internally by parsing the xml, because xml is strings, how is the corresponding objects or class created internally.

For example AddServiceEndpoint

```
AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IDerivativesCalculator), basicHttpBindingObject, Address);
```

how is `DerivativesCalculator.IDerivativesCalculator` from converted to `IDerivativesCalculator`

Comment: Yes, basically the WCF runtime will load and interpret the config and call those methods for you - no black magic involved, just a bit of code. You can easily create an object from it's type as string using `Activator.CreateInstance` (part of base .NET library: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx)

Comment: thanks your one line explains every thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DerivativesCalculator.IDerivativesCalculator` in the XML specifies the name of the interface that defines the contract. `IDerivativesCalculator` is the actual interface, that is defined in the `Derivatives` namespace.

[Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28VS.80%29.aspx) is used to find a type in the assembly. The [Assembly.GetType(String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0cd10tb.aspx) method is an example of a reflection method. This method can be used to return the `IDerivativesCalculator` type, by passing the `DerivativesCalculator.IDerivativesCalculator` name to the method.

Reflection can also be used to [create instances](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dex1ss7c.aspx) of a type, again based on just the name of the type. This is how you can populate an object based on a configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the System.Configuration classes to access the App.config and read in configuration values. [Here is a decent article](http://www.developer.com/net/net/article.php/3396111/Using-Application-Configuration-Files-in-NET.htm) to get you started.